# Adding value of EditorFor to Ajax call within Jquery Function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following jquery function:

```javascript
function SaveMail() {
    subject = $("#MailMsgSubject").val();
    message = $("#MailMsgMessage").val();
    to = To;
    cc = Cc;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ subject: subject, message: message, listTo: to, listCc: cc }),
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveNewMail", "Mail")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#SuccesDiv").html("<b>Your message has been succesfully sent</b>");
        }
    });
}
```

And I have the following view :

```html
<div style="float: left">
    Subject :
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 30.5%">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Subject, new { id = "MailMsgSubject", @style = "width:99%" })
</div>
<div style="clear: both" />

<div style="float: left">
    Priority :@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Priority, new { id = "MailMsgPriority" })
</div>
<div style="float: left">
    Return Receipt :@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.ReturnReceipt, new { id = "MailMsgRR" })
</div>
<div style="float: left">
    Patient :@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Priority, new { id = "MailMsgPatient" })
</div>
<div style="clear: both" />

<div style="float: left">
    Message :
</div>
<div style="clear: both" />

<div style="float: left; width: 35%">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Message, new { id = "MailMsgMessage", @style = "height: 220px; width:100%" })
</div>
<p style="text-align: right">
    <input type="button" id="btnSaveMailMessage" />
</p>
```

My problem is passing the values of the 2 checkboxes i have here ( Priority and Return Receipt) to my JQuery function. EditorFor as i recently found out ( the hard way) has issues accepting a set Id 
Any solutions ? Thanks in advance !

How can i pass those values to my Ajax called controller method "SaveNewMail"

Answer (score 0):

If you need the two checkbox value in the the SaveMail function (controller), you could pass them in the Url.Action by reconstructing the URL.

```
//read the checkboxvalues 
var yourPriorityCheckBoxValue = ?
var yourSendReceiptCheckBoxValue = ?

var urlAction = urlAction + '?priority=__VAR1__&returnReceipt=__VAR2__';
urlAction = urlAction.replace('__VAR1__',yourPriorityCheckBoxValue);
urlACtion = urlAction.replace('__VAR2__',yourSendReceiptCheckBoxValue);
```

Now, in your controller SaveMail Function, read the querystring values.

Hope this helps. there might be an elegant solution than this.

Comment: That would work i guess. But still , it works only for checkboxes and the main reason why I switched to Html.EditorFor is the fact that Html.CheckboxFor doesn't exist. How would I solve this issue ?